# When was Hudson first released?

Tags: hudson, jenkins

I am trying to find out when Kohsuke created Hudson and when the first version of Hudson was released, but I can't find any information on this! Anybody knows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first commit on the repository imported to [Github](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/commit/8a0dc230f44e84e5a7f7920cf9a31f09a54999ac) seems to be date November 5th, 2006.

But in 2006 at JavaOne Kohsuke stated, that the project started in the summer of 2004.